# SQL insert into using Union should add only distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this temp table that has structure like:

```
col1    col2    col3    col3
intID1  intID2  intID3  bitAdd
```

I am doing a union of the values of this temp table with a select query and storing
it into the same temp table.The thing is col3 is not part of the union query I will
need it later on to update the table.

So I am doing like so:

```
Insert into  #temptable
(
intID1,
intID2,
intID3
)
select intID1,intID2,intID3
From
#temptable

UNION

select intID1,intID2,intID3
From
Table A
```

Issue is that I want only the rows that are not already existing in the temp table to be added.Doing it this way will add a duplicate of the already existing row(since union will return one row)How do I insert only those rows not existing in the current temp table in my union query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice and simple with [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO  #temptable (intID1, intID2, intID3)
SELECT intID1,intID2,intID3 FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT intID1,intID2,intID3 FROM #temptable
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE INTO #temptable tmp
USING (select intID1,intID2,intID3 From Table A) t
ON (tmp.intID1 = t.intID1 and tmp.intID2 = t.intID2 and tmp.intID3 = t.intID3)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (intID1,intID2,intID3)
VALUES (t.intID1,t.intID2,t.intID3)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,however sql server version used by us is 2005.I wasn't able to use that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I see where you are coming from. In most programming languages `#temptable` would be a variable (a relation variable or relvar for short) to which you would assign a value (a relation value) thus:

```
#temptable := #temptable UNION A
```

In the relational model, this would achieve the desired result because a relation has no duplicate rows by definition.

However, SQL is not truly relational and does not support assignment. Instead, you are required to add rows to a table using SQL DML `INSERT` statements (which is not so bad: the users of a truly relational database language, if we had one, would no doubt demand a similar shorthand for relational assignment!) but you are also required to do the test for duplicates yourself.

The answers from Daniel Hilgarth and Joachim Isaksson both look good. It's good practice to have two good, logically sound candidate answers then look for criteria (usually performance under typical load) to eliminate one (but retaining it commented out for future re-testing!)